# How to slide the header back in and fix it to the top after it scrolls off the page?

Tags: jquery, css

Initially, my header scrolls along with the page and I would like to make it slide back in from the top with different styles and fix it to the top of the page after it scrolls off the page. After the page scrolls back to header's initial position it should stop being fixed and scroll off the page and slide back in with initial styles. I'm not really good with jquery so can someone tell me how to achieve this?

```
<header class="header">
  <a href="index.html" class="home-link">
    <imgclass="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
  </a>
  <a href="#our-team" class="contact-link">CONTACT</a>
  <div class="menu">
    <button class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze" type="button">
      <span class="hamburger-box">
        <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
      </span>
    </button>
    <nav class="menu-nav">
      <a class="menu-nav-link active" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="menu-nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="menu-nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a class="menu-nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a>
      <a class="menu-nav-link" href="#">Link 5</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adapting a model I got for your from the internet because it has info enough to simulate your request, but this is the basic info you need to use in your work. The idea here is that the script activates after scrolling a certain number of pixels (In this case `100`) and toggles a class to the `header`. But you may manipulate this however you want.

```js
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $("header").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
  } else {
    $("header").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
  }
});
```

```css
header,
a,
img,
li {
  transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: all 1s;
  /* Opera */
}


/* Basic layout */

body {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

img.logo {
  float: left;
}

nav {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section.stretch {
  float: left;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
}

section.stretch p {
  font-family: 'Amaranth', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #969696;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 250px;
}

section.stretch p.bottom {
  top: 100%;
}

header {
  background: #C7C7C7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}

header a {
  color: #969696;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Amaranth', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header a.active,
header a:hover {
  color: #3d3d3d;
}

header li {
  margin-right: 30px;
}


/* Sizes for the bigger menu */

header.large {
  height: 120px;
}

header.large img {
  width: 489px;
  height: 113px;
}

header.large li {
  margin-top: 45px;
}


/* Sizes for the smaller menu */

header.small {
  height: 50px;
}

header.small img {
  width: 287px;
  height: 69px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

header.small li {
  margin-top: 17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="large">
  <nav>
    <img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1d/Comedy_Central_Logo_2011_horizontal.png" />
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Posts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Awesome Freebies</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section class="stretch">
  <p>Descrese the Menu</p>
  <p class="bottom">End.</p>
</section>
```